# How can I obtain a better curvefit in python for my data?

Tags: python, function, curve-fitting

I'm trying to obtain a better curve fit for my data. The model I've obtained does not fit the curve well.

Here's my code:

```
# Data used in model - from dataframe

x1M_5 = df_PEO_EXPT_080223["1M_5_wt%_Shear Rate"]
y1M_5 = df_PEO_EXPT_080223["1M_5_wt%_Viscosity"]

x1M_5 
y1M_5

#CurveFit Cross Model
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def Cross(x, Y0, Yinfinity, A, P):
    y = Yinfinity + ((Y0 - Yinfinity)/(1 - (A*x)**P))
    return(y)

guess = [2.14191448e+04, 5.22945442e+03, 2.24737143e-01, 4.63747120e+02]

popt, pcov = curve_fit(Cross, x1M_5, y1M_5, p0= guess,  maxfev = 100000)
popt
pcov

y_model = Cross(x1M_5, *popt) 

ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

plt.scatter(x1M_5, y1M_5)
plt.plot(x1M_5, y_model, color='r')
plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')

plt.show()
print(popt)
```

[Here's the data (blue) and the fit (red).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxt56.png)

Comment: If you fit the model yourself, which parameters would you expect?

Comment: Looks like the fit got stuck in a local minimum

Comment: @mkrieger1 the 4 parameters I'd expect are in guess: [2.14191448e+04, 5.22945442e+03, 2.24737143e-01, 4.63747120e+02]. I obtained these ones off  an instrument software where I obtained the data, but I'm trying to curvefit myself.

Comment: @mikuszefski do you know how I could fix this?

Comment: What does the plot look like if you use these parameters instead of `popt`?